# Как отправить параметр URL на сервер?

Tags: javascript, html

В URL есть параметр "clickid": https://domain.com/index.php?clickid={clickid}.
Как после получения параметра отправить его на сервер?

Comment: Если вы перешли по этому урлу, то параметр уже на сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вытащить параметр можно так в `js`:

```
    var search = window.location.search.substr(1),
    keys = {};
    search.split('&').forEach(function(item) {
        item = item.split('=');
        keys[item[0]] = item[1];
    });
    console.log(keys);
```

А отправить на сервер через `ajax` Смотря как он у Вас настроен.

К примеру так:

```
var clickid = '1',
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', `http://Ваш_сервер/${clickid}`);
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```